# Bootstrap 4-alpha.6 Jumbotron not working/appearing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bower, bootstrap-4, gulp-sass

I'm learning bootstrap and have the full source compiled via gulp/npm/bower.  I am having trouble getting the jumbotron to display.  Nothing appears not even the text.

I did have trouble with my sass compiling at first when executing gulp but fixed it by commenting out a few lines in the _bootstrap.scss file which were failing because it couldn't find the files to @import.

Everything looks and works good with all other components except the jumbotron itself from the official bootstrap examples.  It does work if I run the page through the CDNs or just launch it through the browser.  But if I compile it via gulp the jumbotron doesn't appear.

Do I need to install additional files or plug-ins to get this running successfully via gulp?

Thanks in advance!

```html
<!-- Main jumbotron for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <div class="container">
        <h1 class="display-3">Hello, world!</h1>
        <p>This is a template for a simple marketing or informational website. It includes a large callout called a jumbotron and three supporting pieces of content. Use it as a starting point to create something more unique.</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

```html
/*!
 * Bootstrap v4.0.0-alpha.2 (http://getbootstrap.com)
 * Copyright 2011-2015 Twitter, Inc.
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)
 */

// Core variables and mixins
@import "bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "bootstrap/scss/mixins";

// Reset and dependencies
@import "bootstrap/scss/normalize";
@import "bootstrap/scss/print";

// Core CSS
@import "bootstrap/scss/reboot";
@import "bootstrap/scss/type";
@import "bootstrap/scss/images";
@import "bootstrap/scss/code";
@import "bootstrap/scss/grid";
@import "bootstrap/scss/tables";
@import "bootstrap/scss/forms";
@import "bootstrap/scss/buttons";

// Components
// @import "bootstrap/scss/animation";
@import "bootstrap/scss/dropdown";
@import "bootstrap/scss/button-group";
@import "bootstrap/scss/input-group";
@import "bootstrap/scss/custom-forms";
@import "bootstrap/scss/nav";
@import "bootstrap/scss/navbar";
@import "bootstrap/scss/card";
@import "bootstrap/scss/breadcrumb";
@import "bootstrap/scss/pagination";
// @import "bootstrap/scss/pager";
// @import "bootstrap/scss/labels";
@import "bootstrap/scss/jumbotron";
@import "bootstrap/scss/alert";
@import "bootstrap/scss/progress";
@import "bootstrap/scss/media";
@import "bootstrap/scss/list-group";
@import "bootstrap/scss/responsive-embed";
@import "bootstrap/scss/close";

// Components w/ JavaScript
@import "bootstrap/scss/modal";
@import "bootstrap/scss/tooltip";
@import "bootstrap/scss/popover";
@import "bootstrap/scss/carousel";

// Utility classes
@import "bootstrap/scss/utilities";
// @import "bootstrap/scss/utilities-background";
// @import "bootstrap/scss/utilities-spacing";
// @import "bootstrap/scss/utilities-responsive";



//Gulfile.js *****

var gulp = require('gulp');
var environments = require('gulp-environments');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var postcss = require('gulp-postcss');
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
var mq4HoverShim = require('mq4-hover-shim');
var rimraf = require('rimraf').sync;
var cssnano = require('gulp-cssnano');
var browser = require('browser-sync');
var panini = require('panini');
var validator = require('gulp-html');
var bootlint  = require('gulp-bootlint');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var scsslint = require('gulp-scss-lint');
var port = process.env.SERVER_PORT || 8080;
var development = environments.development;
var production = environments.production;
var bowerpath = process.env.BOWER_PATH || 'bower_components/';


// Starts a BrowerSync instance
gulp.task('server', ['build'], function(){
  browser.init({server: './_site', port: port});
});

// Watch files for changes
gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch('scss/**/*', ['compile-sass', browser.reload]);
  gulp.watch('html/pages/**/*', ['compile-html']);
  gulp.watch(['html/{layouts,includes,helpers,data}/**/*'], ['compile-html:reset','compile-html']);
});

// Erases the dist folder
gulp.task('clean', function() {
  rimraf('_site');
});

// Copy assets
gulp.task('copy', function() {
  gulp.src(['assets/**/*']).pipe(gulp.dest('_site'));
});

var sassOptions = {
  errLogToConsole: true,
  outputStyle: 'expanded',
  includePaths: bowerpath
};

//gulp.task('sass', function(){
//  return gulp.src('./scss/*.scss') // directory of Sass file you want to compile
//    .pipe(sass()) // converts Sass to CSS with gulp-sass
//    .pipe(gulp.dest('./_site/css/')) // destination of your CSS 
//});

gulp.task('compile-sass', function () {
    var processors = [
        mq4HoverShim.postprocessorFor({ hoverSelectorPrefix: '.bs-true-hover ' }),
        autoprefixer({
            browsers: [
              //
              // Official browser support policy:
              // http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/browsers-devices/#supported-browsers
              //
              'Chrome >= 35', // Exact version number here is kinda arbitrary
              // Rather than using Autoprefixer's native "Firefox ESR" version specifier string,
              // we deliberately hardcode the number. This is to avoid unwittingly severely breaking the previous ESR in the event that:
              // (a) we happen to ship a new Bootstrap release soon after the release of a new ESR,
              //     such that folks haven't yet had a reasonable amount of time to upgrade; and
              // (b) the new ESR has unprefixed CSS properties/values whose absence would severely break webpages
              //     (e.g. `box-sizing`, as opposed to `background: linear-gradient(...)`).
              //     Since they've been unprefixed, Autoprefixer will stop prefixing them,
              //     thus causing them to not work in the previous ESR (where the prefixes were required).
              'Firefox >= 31', // Current Firefox Extended Support Release (ESR)
              // Note: Edge versions in Autoprefixer & Can I Use refer to the EdgeHTML rendering engine version,
              // NOT the Edge app version shown in Edge's "About" screen.
              // For example, at the time of writing, Edge 20 on an up-to-date system uses EdgeHTML 12.
              // See also https://github.com/Fyrd/caniuse/issues/1928
              'Edge >= 12',
              'Explorer >= 9',
              // Out of leniency, we prefix these 1 version further back than the official policy.
              'iOS >= 8',
              'Safari >= 8',
              // The following remain NOT officially supported, but we're lenient and include their prefixes to avoid severely breaking in them.
              'Android 2.3',
              'Android >= 4',
              'Opera >= 12'
            ]
          })
    ];
    return gulp.src('./scss/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(development(sourcemaps.init()))
        .pipe(sass(sassOptions).on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(postcss(processors))
        .pipe(production(cssnano()))
        .pipe(development(sourcemaps.write()))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./_site/css/'));
});

gulp.task('compile-html', function(cb) {
  gulp.src('html/pages/**/*.html')
    .pipe(panini({
      root: 'html/pages/',
      layouts: 'html/layouts/',
      partials: 'html/includes/',
      helpers: 'html/helpers/',
      data: development() ? 'html/data/development' : 'html/data/production'
     }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('_site'));
    //.on('finish', browser.reload);
    cb();
});

gulp.task('compile-html:reset', function(done) {
  panini.refresh();
  done();
});

gulp.task('validate-html',['compile-html'], function() {
  gulp.src('_site/**/*.html')
    .pipe(validator())
    .pipe(bootlint());
});

gulp.task('compile-js', function() {
  return gulp.src([bowerpath+ 'jquery/dist/jquery.min.js', bowerpath+ 'tether/dist/js/tether.min.js', bowerpath+ 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js','js/main.js'])
    .pipe(concat('app.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./_site/js/'));
});
 
gulp.task('scss-lint', function() {
  return gulp.src('scss/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(scsslint({'config': 'scss/.scss-lint.yml'}));
});


gulp.task('set-development', development.task);
gulp.task('set-production', production.task);
gulp.task('test',['scss-lint','validate-html']);
gulp.task('build', ['clean','copy','compile-js','compile-sass','compile-html']);
gulp.task('default', ['set-development','server', 'watch']);
gulp.task('deploy', ['set-production','server', 'watch']);
```

Comment: On a side note, how are you using Bootlint in conjunction with Bootstrap 4?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to install a plugin called `gulp-sass` to compile sass to css

```
npm install gulp-sass --save-dev
```

Second, write this into your gulpfile.js as requirement

```
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
```

The last, declare a gulp task in gulpfile.js

```
gulp.task('sass', function(){
  return gulp.src('app/scss/styles.scss') // directory of Sass file you want to compile
    .pipe(sass()) // converts Sass to CSS with gulp-sass
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css')) // destination of your CSS 
});
```

You can learn more about gulp [here](https://css-tricks.com/gulp-for-beginners/).
Let me know if this is works later. Cheers !

Comment: I tried all the things you mentioned and even added/pasted your code into my gulpfile.js  but I still don't get a Jumbotron in bootstrap which tells me something is out of sync.  I even played around with src/dest directories in the gulfile.js and no luck.  The article is EXTREMELY helpful intro into gulp.  I wish I read that first.  It seems like something is missing from the build somewhere.  I know the CDN and launching the index.html file directly works.  But when I try to run it through the local host I'm missing the jumbotron (maybe more but so far it's all I've tried.)

Comment: I checked the migration page on Bootstrap 4's website and the files I had to comments out from being imported appear to be depricated files and are no longer included.  Any other idea's?  (I'm still reading the article).Let me know and thanks for the info so far.

Comment: Can you post your gulpfile.js ? So, i can see what's wrong with your configuration.

Comment: I thought I added a comment but for some reason it didn't seem to take...  I posted the current state of the Gulpfile.js above at the end of of the bootstrap @import content.  Let me know if you need me to post any additional information. Sorry for the delay but for some reason my comment didn't take.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code snippet

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- Main jumbotron for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1 class="display-3">Hello, world!</h1>
    <p>This is a template for a simple marketing or informational website. It includes a large callout called a jumbotron and three supporting pieces of content. Use it as a starting point to create something more unique.</p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```